# Can I have Redis available in my DDEV container?

Tags: redis, typo3, ddev

I use DDEV as a development environment for a TYPO3 project. I want to have Redis server available (for cache).
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to have Redis available for TYPO3 you need to have:

1. **Redis server**

   To create redis server for your project, just create a file
   `.ddev/docker-compose.redis.yaml` with following
   content:

   ```
   # ddev redis recipe file
   #
   version: '3.6'

   services:
     redis:
       container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-redis
       image: redis:4
       restart: always
       ports:
         - 6379
       labels:         
         com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
         com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
       environment:
         - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
         - HTTP_EXPOSE=6379
       volumes: []
     web:
       links:
         - redis:$DDEV_HOSTNAME
   ```
2. **Configure your application to use Redis**

   Use `redis` as a host, and port `6379`.

Comment: php-fpm isn't run by the standard startup system, it's run by supervisord, so probably just killing it will get a proper restart, `killall php-fpm` instead of /etc/init.d/...  Also, it's a one-word PR to add php-redis :)

Could you please update #3 to be (slightly) more generic as it's completely TYPO3-centric right now.  Maybe we'll get the Drupal version added here soon.

Comment: why using `links`? It's deprecated: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: @stmllr because it is how ddev is handling this currently. See issue opened by me: https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/813

Comment: The post-start hooks can be speeded up a bit and simplified with `apt-get install -y php-redis redis-tools` instead of 2 separate lines/commands. Oh, and don't forget to update this when v1.1.0 comes out in a week or so :) Thanks for your PR to make this easier.

Comment: thats right @rfay I kept them separate, as not everybody needs redis-cli (redis-tools), it's just for verifying if everything works or debugging

Comment: Thanks for maintaining this. Please edit to set `version: `3.6'`

Comment: Thanks! Given that DDev's Redis integration was reverted, this is very useful again. FYI I got an error when installing "redis-tools", but it should work without it.

Answer (score 2):

FYI! DDEV added PHP-Redis to the web container, as of DDEV v1.1.0 on 15 Aug.

https://www.drud.com/ddev-local/ddev-v1-1-0/

> "More services! We’ve added PHP-Redis to the web container. We heard repeatedly that not having Redis was a major hurdle for people who wanted to use DDEV. We hope this helps!"

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 2):

You can get redis with `ddev get drud/ddev-redis`. There's also `ddev get drud/ddev-redis-commander` for use with the ddev redis service.

https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/additional-services/